# How to extract all ToolStripMenuItems of a ContextMenuStrip using recursion?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, contextmenustrip, toolstripitem

I am tryng to extract all items from a ContextMenuStrip to a `List(Of ToolStripMenuItem)`.
I can get the reference of the ContextMenuStrip of a DataGridView, then - with a recursive function - I want to extract the `Name` and `Text` properties of all the `ToolStripMenuItems`, excluding the `ToolStripSeparators`, if any.

I use this code:

```
allItem = New List(Of Control)
Dim lstDbg As List(Of Control) = FindControlRecursive(allItem, form, GetType(DataGridView))

Dim dictRes As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For Each dbgCtrl As Control In lstDbg
    If dbgCtrl.Name <> "" Then
        For Each mnuStrip As ToolStripItem In dbgCtrl.ContextMenuStrip.Items
            If mnuStrip.GetType() = GetType(ToolStripMenuItem) Then
                Dim lstItem As New List(Of ToolStripMenuItem)
                Dim lstTS As List(Of ToolStripMenuItem) = FindControlRecursive_ContextMenu(lstItem, mnuStrip, GetType(ToolStripMenuItem))
                    For Each item As ToolStripMenuItem In lstTS
                        dictRes.Add(item.Name, item.Text)
                    Next
             End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

The function of recursion is `FindControlRecursive_ContextMenu()`:

```
 Public Function FindControlRecursive_ContextMenu(ByVal list As List(Of ToolStripMenuItem), ByVal parent As ToolStripMenuItem, ByVal ctrlType As System.Type) As List(Of ToolStripMenuItem)
    If parent Is Nothing Then Return list
    If parent.GetType Is ctrlType Then
        list.Add(parent)
    End If
    For Each child As ToolStripMenuItem In parent.DropDown.Items
        FindControlRecursive_ContextMenu(list, child, ctrlType)
    Next
    Return list
End Function
```

It works, but if in the DropDown list there is a `ToolStripSeparator`, I don't have the `DropDown.Items` element and the function generates an exception.

How can I skip the ToolStripSeparators and call the recursive function with the next "child"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only sub-items of type [ToolStripMenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem) are needed, you can simply filter the ContextMenuStrip.Items collection beforehand, collecting only Item of that specific type. The [Collection.OfType([Type])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype) method is commonly used for this. `OfType()` only returns Items of the type specified: [ToolStripSeparator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripseparator) is not of that Type, so it won't be included in the filtered collection (nor will other components types such as ToolStripTextBox, ToolStripComboBox etc.).

The recursive function can be an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/iterator) which returns an [`IEnumerable(Of ToolStripMenuItem)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) that yields each item found in a `for each` loop.

Call the main method as, e.g.,:
<sub>► Set `Option Strict`, `Option Explicit` and `Option Infer` to `On`</sub>

```
 Dim cmsItems As Dictionary(Of String, String) = GetAllContextMenuItems(contextMenuStrip1)
```

```
Imports System.Linq

Private Function GetAllContextMenuItems(contextMenu As ContextMenuStrip) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    If contextMenu Is Nothing OrElse (Not contextMenu.HasChildren) Then Return Nothing
    Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    For Each item As ToolStripMenuItem In contextMenu.Items.OfType(Of ToolStripMenuItem)
        dict.Add(item.Name, item.Text)
        For Each subItem In GetSubMenuItems(item)
            dict.Add(subItem.Name, subItem.Text)
        Next
    Next
    Return dict
End Function

Private Iterator Function GetSubMenuItems(parent As ToolStripMenuItem) As IEnumerable(Of ToolStripMenuItem)
    For Each item As ToolStripMenuItem In parent.DropDownItems.OfType(Of ToolStripMenuItem)
        If item.HasDropDownItems Then
            For Each subItem As ToolStripMenuItem In GetSubMenuItems(item)
                Yield subItem
            Next
        Else
            Yield item
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Perfect, I have tested and resolve my problem. I correct for cycle syntax and remove "nothing child" control in GetAllContextMenuItems. Now Extracts exactly want I want.Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, those edits are not necessary, don't change the code here, change your if you want to. The first check-point: `contextMenu.HasChildren`, is there to avoid building a dictionary if the ContextMenuStrip is not null but has no child sub-items to iterate. `child` in `For Each child` doesn't require `as ToolStripMenuItem` because that's the only type inference allowed: the function only returns items of type `ToolStripMenuItem`.

Comment: Sorry, I have test it and without as ToolStripMenuItem I haven't compile. Sorry if I have edit your answer.

Comment: Don't worry about it, no problem in editing the answer, I was explaining why those things are written the way are written. I suppose a VB.Net dev has always set `Option Strict`, `Option Explicit` and `Option Infer` to `On` (which is the same *setup* as C#). If you set `Option Infer On` (unless there's some policy that denies this configuration), you can use this code as it is. Which is more or less the *standard* way. I left a note in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have a nice day.